# session_store.rb cookie key change doesn't change cookie name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, devise

In my rails app I tried changing cookie key like this

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_test_session', domain: :all
```

But when I check browser cookie, key name is still `_session_id`

[image]

Anyone know why key name doesn't change to `_test_session`?

I am using Rails 5.2.4 & Ruby 2.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was rails_admin gem I am using in my application.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/3006 this PR in rails_admin gem hardcode session_store to cookie based. So even though I changed to `cache_store` from `session_store.rb` it was be overridden

Answer (score 0):

Changing the key won't change an EXISTING session cookie name in the user's browser. You have to clear it manually or ignore it. Only subsequent requests will have the changed cookie name.

Comment: after changing the key I restarted rails server & clear browser cache. But still cookie key didn't change